# Determine if object of (x,y) points fall inside of SVG paths

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am working on a D3 graph where I am trying to group scatter points into zones/regions that I have created using path variables. I am looking for some simple, computational way to do this. Here is an example of what I'm working with:

```js
const shallowRightPath = 'M0 25  L0 55  L28 50  L23 25  L0 25'; 
const shallowLeftPath = 'M85 25  L85 55  L57 50  L62 25  L85 25'; 
const shallowCenterPath = 'M28 50  L23 25  L62 25  L57 50  L28 50';
const slotPath = 'M27 89  L32 71  L53 71  L58 89  L27 89';
const deepSlotPath = 'M32 71  L28 50  L57 50  L53 71  L32 71';   
const attackingRightPath = 'M0 55  L0 72  A28 28 1 0 0 5.7 89  L27 89  L32 71  L28 50  L0 55';
const attackingLeftPath = 'M85 55  L85 72  A28 28 0 0 1 79.3 89  L58 89  L53 71  L57 50  L85 55';


const zoneInfo = [
      {"num": 1, "name": "Shallow Right", "path": shallowRightPath, "color":"blue"},
      {"num": 2, "name": "Shallow Left", "path": shallowLeftPath, "color":"yellow"},
      {"num": 3, "name": "Shallow Center Right", "path": shallowCenterPath, "color":"green"},
      {"num": 4, "name": "Slot", "path": slotPath, "color":"green"},
      {"num": 5, "name": "Deep Slot", "path": deepSlotPath, "color":"red"},
      {"num": 6, "name": "Attacking Right", "path": attackingRightPath, "color":"yellow"},
      {"num": 7, "name": "Attacking Left", "path": attackingLeftPath, "color":"blue"}

];

// append shaded paths
const shades = d3.select('svg').append('g')
for(var i = 0; i < zoneInfo.length; i++) {
  shades.append("path")
    .attr("d", zoneInfo[i].path)
    .attr("fill", zoneInfo[i].color)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", '0.3')
    .attr("opacity", 0.85);
}

const points = [
  {x: 15, y: 35, zonenum: ""},
  {x: 29, y: 35, zonenum: ""},
  {x: 59, y: 55, zonenum: ""},
  {x: 45, y: 75, zonenum: ""},
  {x: 57, y: 49, zonenum: ""}
]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Most of these paths are trapezoids and other odd quadrilaterals, and computing the zones for each point by a series of inequalities based on the functions of the lines of the trapezoids would take some considerable time (unless I had a function to do that as well).

Is there an easier way to determine which zone my list of points falls into? Thanks!

Comment: As a >10kRP user I can see your deleted comment (in your deleted answer), so I'd like to explain: d3 graphs do not have the y axis reversed! This actually has nothing to do with D3, it's an SVG spec instead: in SVG (and HTML canvas as well), the origin is at the top left corner. Therefore, in both SVG and canvas, the y coordinate increases as we move down, not up, like in a common cartesian system.

Answer (score 1):

If you can convert the paths to an array of arrays with the coordinates, like...

```
[[85, 25], [85, 55], [57, 50], [62, 25], [85, 25]]
```

... you could use [d3.polygonContains()](https://github.com/d3/d3-polygon), which...

> Returns true if and only if the specified point is inside the specified polygon.

For instance, filtering your `zoneInfo` array and assigning the `num` value to the respective point:

```
points.forEach(function(d) {
  d.zonenum = zoneInfo.filter(function(e) {
    return d3.polygonContains(e.polygon, [d.x, d.y])
  })[0].num
});
```

Here is a demo with some of your paths and points:

```js
const zoneInfo = [{
    "num": 1,
    "name": "Shallow Right",
    "color": "blue",
    "polygon": [
      [0, 25],
      [0, 55],
      [28, 50],
      [23, 25],
      [0, 25]
    ]
  },
  {
    "num": 2,
    "name": "Shallow Left",
    "color": "yellow",
    "polygon": [
      [85, 25],
      [85, 55],
      [57, 50],
      [62, 25],
      [85, 25]
    ]
  },
  {
    "num": 3,
    "name": "Shallow Center Right",
    "color": "green",
    "polygon": [
      [28, 50],
      [23, 25],
      [62, 25],
      [57, 50],
      [28, 50]
    ]
  },
  {
    "num": 4,
    "name": "Slot",
    "color": "green",
    "polygon": [
      [27, 89],
      [32, 71],
      [53, 71],
      [58, 89],
      [27, 89]
    ]
  },
  {
    "num": 5,
    "name": "Deep Slot",
    "color": "red",
    "polygon": [
      [32, 71],
      [28, 50],
      [57, 50],
      [53, 71],
      [32, 71]
    ]
  }
];


const points = [{
    x: 15,
    y: 35,
    zonenum: ""
  },
  {
    x: 29,
    y: 35,
    zonenum: ""
  },
  {
    x: 45,
    y: 75,
    zonenum: ""
  },
  {
    x: 57,
    y: 49,
    zonenum: ""
  }
];

points.forEach(function(d) {
  d.zonenum = zoneInfo.filter(function(e) {
    return d3.polygonContains(e.polygon, [d.x, d.y])
  })[0].num
});

console.log(points)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution in R did the trick for me

```
createZones <- function(xvals, yvals) {

    getM <- function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
      return((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1))
    }
    getB <- function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
      slopeM <- (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
      return(y1 - slopeM*x1)
    }


    # based on xScale inverted due to d3 coordinates
    zonenumbers = rep(0, length(xvals))
    zonenames = rep("", length(xvals))

    zonenumbers[which(yvals <= 25)] <- 1
    zonenames[which(yvals <= 25)] <- 'Neutral Zone'

    zonenumbers[which(yvals > 25 & 
                        yvals > getM(23, 25, 28, 50) * xvals + getB(23, 25, 28, 50) & 
                        yvals < getM(0, 55, 28, 50) * xvals + getB(0, 55, 28, 50))] <- 2
    zonenames[which(yvals > 25 & 
                      yvals > getM(23, 25, 28, 50) * xvals + getB(23, 25, 28, 50) & 
                      yvals < getM(0, 55, 28, 50) * xvals + getB(0, 55, 28, 50))] <- 'Shallow Right'

    zonenumbers[which(yvals > 25 & 
                        yvals < getM(57, 50, 85, 55) * xvals + getB(57, 50, 85, 55) & 
                        yvals > getM(57, 50, 62, 25) * xvals + getB(57, 50, 62, 25))] <- 3
    zonenames[which(yvals > 25 & 
                      yvals < getM(57, 50, 85, 55) * xvals + getB(57, 50, 85, 55) & 
                      yvals > getM(57, 50, 62, 25) * xvals + getB(57, 50, 62, 25))] <- 'Shallow Left'

    zonenumbers[which(yvals > 25 & yvals <= 50 &  
                        yvals < getM(23, 25, 28, 50) * xvals + getB(23, 25, 28, 50) & 
                        yvals < getM(57, 50, 62, 25) * xvals + getB(57, 50, 62, 25))] <- 4
    zonenames[which(yvals > 25 & yvals <= 50 & 
                      yvals < getM(23, 25, 28, 50) * xvals + getB(23, 25, 28, 50) & 
                      yvals < getM(57, 50, 62, 25) * xvals + getB(57, 50, 62, 25))] <- 'Shallow Center'

    zonenumbers[which(yvals > 71 & yvals <= 89 &
                        yvals > getM(27, 89, 32, 71) * xvals + getB(27, 89, 32, 71) & 
                        yvals > getM(53, 71, 58, 89) * xvals + getB(53, 71, 58, 89))] <- 5
    zonenames[which(yvals > 71 & yvals <= 89 & 
                      yvals > getM(27, 89, 32, 71) * xvals + getB(27, 89, 32, 71) & 
                      yvals > getM(53, 71, 58, 89) * xvals + getB(53, 71, 58, 89))] <- 'Slot'

    zonenumbers[which(yvals > 50 & yvals <= 71 & 
                        yvals < getM(32, 71, 28, 50) * xvals + getB(32, 71, 28, 50) & 
                        yvals < getM(57, 50, 53, 71) * xvals + getB(57, 50, 53, 71))] <- 6
    zonenames[which(yvals > 50 & yvals <= 71 & 
                      yvals < getM(27, 89, 32, 71) * xvals + getB(27, 89, 32, 71) & 
                      yvals < getM(53, 71, 58, 89) * xvals + getB(53, 71, 58, 89))] <- 'Deep Slot'

    zonenumbers[which(yvals <= 89 &  
                        yvals < getM(27, 89, 32, 71) * xvals + getB(27, 89, 32, 71) & 
                        yvals > getM(32, 71, 28, 50) * xvals + getB(32, 71, 28, 50) &
                        yvals > getM(28, 50, 0, 55) * xvals + getB(28, 50, 0, 55))] <- 7
    zonenames[which(yvals <= 89 &
                      yvals < getM(27, 89, 32, 71) * xvals + getB(27, 89, 32, 71) & 
                      yvals > getM(32, 71, 28, 50) * xvals + getB(32, 71, 28, 50) &
                      yvals > getM(28, 50, 0, 55) * xvals + getB(28, 50, 0, 55))] <- 'Attacking Right'

    zonenumbers[which(yvals <= 89 &
                        yvals < getM(58, 89, 53, 71) * xvals + getB(58, 89, 53, 71) & 
                        yvals > getM(53, 71, 57, 50) * xvals + getB(53, 71, 57, 50) &
                        yvals > getM(57, 50, 85, 55) * xvals + getB(57, 50, 85, 55))] <- 8
    zonenames[which(yvals <= 89 &
                      yvals < getM(58, 89, 53, 71) * xvals + getB(58, 89, 53, 71) & 
                      yvals > getM(53, 71, 57, 50) * xvals + getB(53, 71, 57, 50) &
                      yvals > getM(57, 50, 85, 55) * xvals + getB(57, 50, 85, 55))] <- 'Attacking Left'

    zonenumbers[which(yvals > 89)] <- 9 
    zonenames[which(yvals > 89)] <- 'Behind The Net'

    return(data.frame(zonenumber = zonenumbers, zonename = zonenames, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  }
```